# Tablesorter set filter setup to multiple columns

Tags: filter, multiple-columns, tablesorter

I have found a filter configuration in order to filter empty columns.
The issue is that I only know how to apply this to one column (In the example column number 8).I want to apply this to other columns at the same time (For instance columns 8, 12 and 17).
Thank you!

```
filter_functions: {
            8: {
                '{empty}' : function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
                    return $.trim(e) === '';
                }
            }
        },
        filter_selectSource: {
            8: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
                // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
                var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
                // manipulate the array as desired, then return it
                array.push('{empty}');
                return array;
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the [`filter_functions`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-functions) and the [`filter_selectSource`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) options will accept an object key containing a jQuery selector, as well as a zero-based column index. For example, if column headers 8, 12 and 17 all had the class name of "add-empty", then set the options as follows:

```
filter_functions: {
  '.add-empty' : {
    '{empty}' : function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
      return $.trim(e) === '';
    }
  }
},
filter_selectSource: {
  '.add-empty' : function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
    // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
    var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
    // manipulate the array as desired, then return it
    array.push('{empty}');
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mister Mottie!! I have also found that if in a regular filter you tap: "" you will filter only the empty cells also.

Comment: Just open and close double quotes like this -> ""